# Switching to a different projection based on zoom level

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I have a map on my Geoserver, which I am displaying via wms and Openlayers. I am using a projection that is optimal for the whole area. However, when zooming in I would like to switch to a different projection which has proved to be best for a particular locality.

How can I achieve this? Any examples out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methodology would be to detect a zoom change and apply a updated view with the new projection to the map.

First you have to detect the change of the resolution:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', changeProjection);
```

Secondly you look if you have reached the desired zoom level and then apply the projection:

```
var changeProjection = function() {
  var zoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom();

  // look if zoom level is reached
  if (zoomLevel > 15) {

    //define new view and apply to map
    map.setView(new ol.View({
      center: map.getView().getCenter(),
      zoom: zoomLevel,
      projection: newProjection /* typeof == ol.proj.ProjectionLike */
  });
}
```

Note: The code is untested and you have to set variable newProjection to make it work.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like what I am looking for. However, it is not working, I am unable to switch to the new projection (my layer becomes invisible after executing setView).

Comment: You are right. I just created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/dd92fmkx/1/) but after changing zoom level layer becomes invisible. hmm, a bug or a feature?

Comment: I have found that it works if I set center to `ol.proj.transform(map.getView().getCenter(), 'EPSG:32622', 'EPSG:3574')`. I agree with you that it must be a bug.